# Downloading image from server without file extension (NSData to UIImage)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsdata, nsurl

From my server I'm pulling down a url that is supposed to simply be a profile image. The relevant code for pulling down the image from the urls is this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kBaseURL,profile_image_url];
profilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
```

My url is in the format (note no file extension on the end since its dynamically rendered)

```
localhost:8000/people/1/profile_image
```

If I load the url in my browser the image displays; however the code above for pulling down the UIImage does not work. I've verified that the code does pull an image from a random site on the interwebs.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: after executing the above code, what are u getting on your console. I have tried many methods in my project to display pic from server and the most prominent issue i have found is that by default, your localhost folders are read only and you need to change permission as well.... Initially i thought read only wudnt matter if i am just loading the picture beacuse technically i am only reading the contents , right. But it did matter. Try doing that as well and also let me know what you are getting on your console

Comment: One more thing, is the name of your image containing white spaces, if they are then you need to remove white spaces from your image name while making URL request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it work if you feed NSURL

```
http://localhost:8000/people/1/profile_image
```

I imagine that the http:// is important here (so that the NSURL knows whether it's pointing at a file or  remote URL).

Comment: +1 Apple is very, very picky about what URLs it lets you load.  http and itms are two of the ones it allows.  I've had similar problems and found this to be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks jeff this solved my problem. Had to dance a bit because I've stubbed the server and am using file:// as well but this solved my problem perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't display it in a UIImageView is because the `UIImageView` doesn't know what format it's in (jpeg,png,etc.) 

A good way for future coding is *always* use extensions. *Don't* take short cuts, they will always end up worse and you'll have to fix them over and over again.

Comment: The image isn't a static asset image so I have no way to know the extension before hand. The server just spits out whatever is uploaded to it.

Answer (score 0):

First check for the following :

**Permissions: change from read only to read and write.**

I have tried many methods in my project to display pic from server and the most prominent issue i have found is that by default, your localhost folders are read only and you need to change permission as well.... Initially i thought read only wudnt matter if i am just loading the picture beacuse technically i am only reading the contents , right. But it did matter.

**White Spaces**

One more thing you coud check for is the name of your image containing white spaces, if they are then you need to remove white spaces from your image name while making URL request.

**Try adding extensions if nothing works out**
If eveythings fine , try to load the image with extensions which would obviously work.

**Provide us with some initial coding as well**

Let us know about your **code snippets and console outputs** which could help the community to reach the solution of the problem in a more prominent manner.